# CSS, phpBB and <td> background-color

Tags: css, background-color, phpbb

I am implementing a phpBB forum and I find that the font color palette is not visible when it should be.  I followed this post https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=2096426 but it didn't help.

Here is some background:

My main.css page contains this:

```
tr, th, td {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;}
```

The color palette as drawn by phpBB is as so:

```
<div id="colour_palette" style="display: block;">
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#808000" style="width: 15px; height: 10px;">
<a onclick="bbfontstyle('[color=#808000]', '[/color]'); return false;" href="#">
<img width="15" height="10" title="#808000" alt="#808000" src="images/spacer.gif">
</a>
</td>
```

In an effort to override the transparency on  as set in main.css, I added the following to the main.css document:

```
#colour_palette td {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

AND I edited the phpBB javascript so that the color palette 's are now written as follows:

```
<td style="width: 15px; height: 10px; background-color=#BF8040;">
<a onclick="bbfontstyle('[color=#BF8040]', '[/color]'); return false;" href="#">
</td>
```

but the color palette is still invisible.

I would appreciate any and all suggestions.

Comment: I found the answer while re-reading my post:

Comment: <td style="width: 15px; height: 10px; background-color=#BF8040;">

A change from background-color= in the line a bove to background-color: was the answer. Code works as follows:

    <td style="width: 15px; height: 10px; background-color:#BF8040;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer while re-reading my post:

A change from background-color= in the line above to background-color: was the answer. Code works as follows: